# How to validate input within a bool to begin with two 0's using substring

Tags: c#

I am real stumped regarding a specific validation, I need to validate that the user has inputted two 0's before their user ID. This is what I have tried so far:

```
if (txtID.Text.Substring(0, 2) != "00")
{
    DisplayMessage("Your ID must begin with two zeros.");
    txtID.Focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do this on keypress, or just on enter?

Comment: Maybe `if (txtID.Text.Length >= 2 && !txtID.Text.StartWith("00")) { ... }` or `if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtID.Text, @"^00\d*$")) { ... }` ?

Comment: This is done as a validation upon the user clicking the enter button

Comment: So what is your problem? Your code will work fine for this (only need to check if `txtID.Text` length is 2 or more). Also, there is a typo. I think there should be `txtID.Text.Substring(` in your sample.

Comment: be careful of invalid input that could throw an exception

Comment: ahh yes that did the trick vasily! It was simply a typo on my end, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: you can check for Trim() and string.IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
if (txtID.Text.Length >= 2 && txtID.Trim().StartsWith("00", true, null))
{
    DisplayMessage("Your ID must begin with two zeros.");
    txtID.Focus();
    return false;
}
```

Although not relevant in this case, StartsWith comes with multiple overloads (case sensitive, case insensitive, culture specific)..

Comment: Why do you `.Trim()` before `.StartsWith()`?

Comment: someone can enter " 00test". trim removes leading or trailing whitespaces

Comment: Also, Substring(0,2) is very buggy. if someone enters 0 only, Substring(0,2) will fail and cause System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Agreed, `.Substring(0, 2)` is not a great solution, but I'm talking about `.Trim()`. So, if some one enters " 00test" - your code will pass it and no message will show. But I can see, that this text is diffenetly not starting with "00", it start with " 0". Now I need to remember to `.Trim()` the value from this textbox all the time i use it? Is'n it better to raise a message about leading spaces?

Comment: yup, how to go about this is more of a logical issue. the word different is based on each other perspective

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with User Experience would tell you that if they have to enter `00`, don't make them enter it at all, it's a *bad user experience*.  Instead make it easy on your user and do it for them:

[image]